# change column name inside Webservice C#

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

i have not work in C# much, i need to change the column name of oEmployee 2nd and 3rd column.

as web service is calling from APP for very fast Fixed of one issue express way is to change name of column in web service itself.

is there possible to achieve ?

i tried :

dt4.Columns[1].ColumnName = 'Col1' or dt4.Columns[1].Caption , nothing working..

```
    Employee oEmployee = new Employee(strConnString);

    oEmployee.Query.AddResultColumn(EmployeeSchema.EmployeeID);

    oEmployee.Query.AddResultColumn(EmployeeSchema.FirstName);

    oEmployee.Query.AddResultColumn(EmployeeSchema.LastName);

    oEmployee.Query.Load();

    dt = oEmployee.DefaultView.Table;

    dt.TableName = "Table1";

    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
```

is it possible to change column name as the way we can change table name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are very close. Try,

```
 dt = oEmployee.DefaultView.Table;

 //Debug and make sure that you are changing the name for the correct column
 dt.Columns[1].ColumnName = "New Column Name"; 

 dt.TableName = "Table1";
```

Here is an snapshot from my code and it will give you idea on how I am changing the value,

[image]